# Hibernate No value specified for parameter

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, jpql

I have a named query that retrieves `UgAcyearExamSchedule` interms of a LIST as follows:

```
@NamedQuery(name="UgAcyearExamSchedule.getByDetail", 
query="select u FROM UgAcyearExamSchedule u where 
u.ugAcyearExamScheduleDetails=:ugDetails")
```

where `ugAcyearExamScheduleDetails` is defined in `UgAcyearExamSchedule` as follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="ugAcyearExamSchedule")
private List<UgAcyearExamScheduleDetail> ugAcyearExamScheduleDetails;
```

when i tried to set the parameter for these query as follows:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("UgAcyearExamSchedule.getByDetailAndDeptYear");
query.setParameter("ugDetails",details);
List<UgAcyearExamSchedule> examSChedules = (List<UgAcyearExamSchedule>) query.getResultList();
```

the following exception arrises:

```
ERROR: No value specified for parameter
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

I don't know the main cause of these problem,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You define a named query with name "`UgAcyearExamSchedule.getByDetail`" yet you are invoking the named query with name "`UgAcyearExamSchedule.getByDetailAndDeptYear`". I'd suggest that you have an extra parameter (deptYear?) on this other named query (that you haven't posted), so it complains about the extra parameter.

Also you cannot really use "collectionField = :collectionParam" in JPQL. It is more portable to check on the "MEMBER OF" for the elements.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are not using Named Queries correctly. I noticed you use the `createNamedQuery` method, however your Named Query already exists; you need to call it.

I suppose that your `em` stands for EntityManager or similar, so if you are making your queries with an instance of Hibernate Session Factory you should try using `getNamedQuery` instead:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("UgAcyearExamSchedule.getByDetailAndDeptYear")
             .setParameter("ugDetails",details);
```

Make Sure that your `details` variable is actually set to something. Also make sure that you are using Hibernate Session correctly.

Some links that may help you :)

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/

Comment: He is using JPA API (EntityManager) not Hibernate API (SessionFactory). createNamedQuery is what he is supposed to use. Here's a link that may help you http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#Named_Query